# Cant access wamp server(localhost) for my social android app?

Tags: android, mysql

I finished creating my social app yesterday and uploaded it to the Play Store. Using the ip address `http://192.168.56.1/index.php` on an emulator, it was working, but now in a real android device, it doesn't work.

How can I fix this issue ?

I even assigned my ip address but didn't work.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify wht the IP address refers to ? Is this a WebService used by the app ?

Comment: The link for my wamp server.

Comment: `192.168.*.*` is your local network, so you need to have a public IP address to be used from your app.

Comment: OK, is the phone on the same network (Wifi I guess) ? Are the ports opened on your wamp server machive for external access ?

Comment: It's stupid but how can i find my IP address. I used cmd `ipconfig` but didn't help. I even used `http://www.whatsmyip.org/` for my IP address but failed.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 change your ipaddress to this

Comment: No it's a real device. I mean it's social app, and everyone should have access for the `php` in order to store the user data to mysql.

Comment: https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-my-public-ip-address/

Comment: Hi your IP address is local show if you are using device which is not connected with network then it is not work, for the work you require to host any server and setup ip address live.

Comment: @LMS My ip address looks strange something like this:` 2a02:908:c33:3fc0:c83b:......`

Comment: This is your address mac, not your public IP @, checkout my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy you are trying to access to your local server from a remote device, so this is normal! you have to put your web services in an online server (PUBLIC IP) ... The application keep working for you because you already have **WAMP server runing localy**, if you turn down your server it won't work anymore .. The android device doesn't have access to your WAMP, unlike the emulator!

**Note:** If you put your WAMP online, you can manage to run your android application, but this is not a good solution because you need something available 7/7 & 24/24 ( a web server ), you can host your scripts on a shared hosting server for a cheap price ..

Comment: But I want to use my local server for sometime and will upgrade to a shared hosting server later.

Comment: You will have then to make your local server connected to the world! it's not really recommended and you can do this if you correctly configure your WAMP .. but I suggest you to use any free hosting server at least!

Comment: try this one https://www.000webhost.com/ and then you can move to a paid shared server later

Comment: Used it for some of my additional projects. This server gets hacked, I mean for a social app maybe not a good idea.

Comment: Yea you are right! But at least you can test you application before moving to a real server ... If you can affoard 2$/month .. you can use this hosting server it's really cheap! https://service.leapswitch.com/aff.php?aff=307
(I put my referral link, but i'be been using this server for years, it's really good price/quality ..)

Comment: Will give it a try! What do you think of google's cloud platform? You get a 60 days trial.

Comment: For sure google cloud would be a better option! But it depends from how much you are willing to pay, if you just launched your application, starting by something small is a good idea! You don't need such a complicated/fast cloud for now, if you got alot of traffic then after 1 or 2 months you can migrate your data .. you just export your mysql and import it in the new cloud ..